# how to fix or investigate 'Operation "view_ws_is_ws_view" failed'?

Tags: clearcase

I stopped and started a view for which various file access actions were hanging (after killing all my terminal sessions where I was using that view), and now get:

```
cleartool: Error: Operation "view_ws_is_ws_view" failed: view storage directory or control files unavailable --
additional information may be present in the view server host's view log.
```

Two questions:

1) Is there a clearcase subsystem that can be restarted to fix this (preferably without impacting other users)?

2) the very unhelpful error message refers to a view log, but doesn't say where it is.  Where can this log be found (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3  (x86_64))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> clearcase subsystem that can be restarted to fix this

You can start by ending the `view_server.exe` associated to this view ([`cleartool endview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_endview.htm)):

```
cleartool endview -server <view_tag>
```

Then:

```
cleartool startview <view_tag>
```

> Where can this log be found

This would use the [`cleartool getlog`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm) command, for local logs, but also for logs from the ClearCase view server (accessible from your client workstation)

```
cleartool getlog -tag <view_tag>
```

To display the last 10 lines of the `view` logs (logs for any view):

```
cleartool getlog -host <server_name> view
```

To display  view log entries within 20 minutes of 4:00 P.M. on June 19:

```
cleartool getlog -host <server_name> -around 19-Jun.14:00 20 view
```

---

See also (in addition of the above recommendations) the [IBM technote swg21131145](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21131145) or [technote swg21131682](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21131682).

If above isn't enough, I like to [`fix_prot` the view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21142606) in order to avoid any right access issue.

If your view is on Unix, for instance:

```
alias sfp sudo /usr/atria/etc/utils/fix_prot
sfp -force -rec -chown <user> -chgrp <group> -chmod 775 /path/to/views/storage/<view_tag>.vws
sfp -force -root -chown <user> -chgrp <group>  /path/to/views/storage/<view_tag>.vws
```