# view_server.exe(pid): Error: Unexpected error in VOB

Tags: clearcase

Here is the error:

```
view_server.exe(pid): Error: Unexpected error in VOB 
"<registry_host>:E:\ClearCase_Storage_e\vobs\AdmitOneIKE.vbs" 
op vob_ob_get_vob_owner_sid:error detected by ClearCase subsystem
See vobrpc_server_log on host <registry host>
```

While I try to create a new view in view server.
It is unable to mount `vob` from registry server.

Comment: What does a `cleartool getlog vobrpc_server` gives you? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24308061/6309)

Comment: There no items to show. No error in vobrpc_server log.

Comment: Did you do a `getlog` on the right host?

Comment: yes. Both the registry and view servers, I checked the logs.