# Credentails Manager service is stopped

Tags: clearcase

[image]

Hi,

I am getting the below error when trying to update my view . Also, creds manager service is stopped and not getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the credmanager.exe is not started, none of the view (snapshot or dynamic) will work. So you need to debug that first.
Typically, you would check the ClearCase logs, and the Windows event, to see what the issue is. See "[how to fix or investigate 'Operation “view_ws_is_ws_view” failed'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24308061/6309)", using [`cleartool getlog`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm).

That kind of error ("`This application has failed to start because`libatriaks.dll`was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem`") was seen with rather old versions of ClearCase (7.0.1).
See for instance [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014079272).

> If the DLL is present and the directory is in your path you should never
>   get this error.
>   Check to see how far `...\rational\clearcase\bin` is down your SYSTEM path, and make sure the DLL's are in there.
>   `ccgzip.exe` will be called (by the client process) when checking in any files that fall back to the "compressed_file" element type. It may be called by the view server during file opens and checkouts to construct `cleartext` if needed. The former uses your user path, the latter will normally use the SYSTEM path.
>
> We've seen odd behavior on Windows when the path gets >500 characters
>   long, though there seems to be no "official" limit to the length this environment variable (`%PATH%`) can grow to.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you see is likely a path issue. Whether that's related to the other issue is unknown...

Is the albd server process running? The credential manager service is flagged to depend on this service. If that service fails to start, or terminates, the credential manager service will also fail.

A service startup failure should be in the Application or System Event logs. and from there the "Troubleshooting albd startup failures" technote on ibm.com would likely be a good place to start.